# Output random hex values from within a range in python

Tags: python

I am able to generate random hex values in a specific range using the code below, but I get the same random value on each line if i set my counter to more than 1. I'm guessing I need a loop, I have tried with "for x in range" but my implementation must be wrong as it overflows. I'm new to python and have searched for days but can't seem to find how to implement it correctly.

```
    import random
    import sys

    #ran = random.randrange(2**64)
    ran = random.randrange(0x8000000000000000, 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF)
    myhex = "%064x" % ran

    #limit string to 64 characters
    myhex = myhex[:64]

    counter = 0

    file = open('output.txt', 'w')
    sys.stdout = file

    for result in myhex:
    print(myhex)
    counter += 1
    if counter > 10:
    break
```

Comment: You are only generating one random number. If you want to generate multiple random numbers in a loop, you need to put the call to `random` inside the loop.

Comment: `myhex` is not given a new value, no. The output of the `"%064x" % ran` expression is not 'live', it is **just a string**. Put your `ran = ...` and `myhex = ...` assigments *in the loop* so they are executed more than once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, you're generating the random number only once. To have a new random value for each iteration, you need to put the generation code in the loop as follows:

```
# ... your imports

with open('output.txt', 'w') as f:
    for _ in range(10):
        ran = random.randrange(0x8000000000000000, 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF)
        myhex = "%064x" % ran
        #limit string to 64 characters
        myhex = myhex[:64]
        f.write(myhex)
        f.write("\n")
```

Also, if you want to dump the results in a file, a better approach is to write directly to the file without changing `sys.stdout`, as done in the above code.

Comment: Why we are doing "myhex = "%064x" % ran" here? @Sam

Comment: To format the variable `ran` as a hex string @SumitSomani